# Maths Olympiad problem relating to circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

---

Given:

HG is the common tangent to circle C and J.

Prove:

$\angle{HFI} = \angle{HFG}$ or $HF$ bisects $\angle{GFI}$

---

My attempt:

$$\angle{FHG} + \angle {HGL} = \angle{LIF} + \angle {LFI}$$

$$\begin{align} \Rightarrow \angle{LFI}  = &\angle{FHG} + \angle {HGL} - \angle {LIF} \\  =   &\angle{IFG} + \angle {LGF} - \angle {HGF} - \angle {HFG}+ \angle {HGL} \\ = & \angle{IFG} + \angle {LGF} - \angle {LGF} - \angle {HFG} \\ = & \angle{IFG} - \angle {HFG} \end{align}$$

$$\angle{LFI} + \angle {HFG} = \angle{IFG}$$

which is not of any interest to me.

However I start, I end at $\angle{LFI} + \angle {HFG} = \angle{IFG}$

A hint or two might be helpful.
Thanks.

**Note**: this was a problem in an Olympiad problem where 3 hours are given for solving 10 question subjectively, so I don't think there is a trick answer to this question.

Comment: which problem in which olympiad?

Comment: @miracle173 it is a very old question of 2009 KvsJmo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Since $HG$ is tangent to the circle $J$, 
$$\angle{GHF}=\angle{HIF}$$

Similarly, letting $M\ (\not=F)$ be the point both on $IF$ and on the circle $C$, 
$$\angle{HGF}=\angle{GMF}=\angle{FEI}=\angle{FHI}$$

Now, consider the triangles $\triangle{FGH},\triangle{HFI}$ to get the result.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: How can i know which constructions i have to do in a geometric problem ? like how do know that we have to make those construction to solve this problem.

Comment: @A---B: In our question, I wanted to use the condition that $HG$ is tangent to the circle $C$. That's the reason for my taking $M$. (one can consider the condition that one has not used yet.)

Comment: I can't see how $\angle{GMF}$ helps show that $\angle{HGF}=\angle{FEI}$. So far, the only way I see how to show that is by considering the triangles $\triangle{GXE}$ and $\triangle{FXG}$, where $X$ is the unlabeled point in $HG$.

Comment: @Wood: The quadrilateral $EGMF$ is inscribed in the circle $C$, so $\angle{GMF}+\angle{GEF}=180^\circ$. Therefore, $\angle{FEI}=180^\circ -\angle{GEF}=\angle{GMF}$. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Direct one-line proof:  $\angle GFH = \angle GFE + \angle EFH = \angle HGE + \angle EHG = \angle HEI = \angle HFI$.

*Nothing extra constructed!*

Comment: Not all olympiad problems are hard. =) By the way, this result implies $GH \parallel KI$.

Comment: it requires two construction. Thanks by the  way.

Comment: @A---B: Usually it makes sense to only count points constructed, otherwise almost every problem needs many extra constructions, and it becomes meaningless to ask for solutions with few or none of them.